# grails invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Tags: hibernate, grails, null

I get this error when I try to insert data into my database (postgresql)
Using `replace("\\x00", " ")` I managed to "solve" it, but is there a way to save NULL fields using postgresql?